# Where are template prerequisites being loaded from?

Tags: javascript, joomla

My Joomla 2.5 site is now using https instead of http.

I'm getting the typical warning `"Mixed content"` warning in most browsers.
Chrome is blocking things like:

http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css

Now, the problem is WHERE is the script loading this stylesheet? I know it must be loaded by the template but I just can't find it.

Tried `index.php` both in the public_html and template folders but since they're just PHP files including other PHP files and libraries, including other scripts, etc... it seems impossible.

This is probably possible to fix using javascript. I tried the following to fix the IFrames:

```
iframes=document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');

for (i=0; i<iframes.length; i++){
   var antigoURL=iframes[i].src;
   var novoURL=antigoURL.replace("http:", "");
   iframes[i].src=novoURL;
};
```

But since the script runs AFTER the page is loaded, I can't prevent the error to show up.

My site is [www.portal-gestao.com](https://www.portal-gestao.com)

The template I'm using is Base3 from http://demo.joomlabamboo.com/

I know this should be easy, but I'm still struggling.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: It'll probably be loaded dynamically in the tempalte's XML or helper files. Since you haven't mentioned what temlpate, we really can't say much more.

Comment: Thanks, please see my the URLs in my edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is not loaded from template, then it must be loaded from an extension such as module, component, or plugin.

I would download a copy of the entire Joomla site then just run a search (find) on all files with your favorite text editor looking for the reference.  Once you identify where the reference is called you can determine the most optimal way to call the contents of the file in https.

Since the external file may not be hosted in https from the external source, you can just copy all the CSS and paste into a template CSS file and remove the reference from the extension code. But, the next time you update the extension it may put the reference back in so you will need to watch that.

Comment: Thanks @BradM, I did download a copy to my PC and tried a search using Windows for "http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" and other similar things but it did not return any results.

Comment: I found it! It was a module, the reference was being called from a PHP script, thanks for your help!